# Can QR decomposition find zero eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to write code using QR decomposition from scratch in C which calculates eigenvalue of graph laplacian $\mathbf{L}$ on two-dimensional lattice with periodic boundary condition. Here is a relatively simple? example, length of lattice is $l=3$, and the number of site is $N=l^2=9$:

$$
\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{D} - \mathbf{A} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My code works very well in other $\mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ matrix but it cannot calculate last one eigenvalue of $\mathbf{L}$. As calculating it on https://matrixcalc.org/, I think I found why my code does not work. Its eigenvalues are $\lambda = 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3,$ and $0$. Maybe my code has some fault but I want to know about it can be corrected or not before modify my code.

Here is my question. Can the QR decomposition find an eigenvalue of zero?